# Form submits twice

Tags: php, html, forms, http, double-submit-problem

I have a form that processes a payment, but approximately one in every 300 payments comes though twice, my logs show that there were two requests for all these occurrences.

I implemented some JavaScript that disables the submit button after it's clicked, and it seems to work fine for me, but I'm still getting double submissions every now and then.

Does anyone know anything else that could be causing the form to be submitted twice?

Comment: What are the time deltas between the duplicate submissions? It is possible that the user went back, and then re-submitted. Also, what User-Agent?

Comment: probably an issue with users, they are never to smart :-). you can not rely on js alone, it can be disabled, you need to some server side checking.

Comment: This is where it gets weird, the request times vary by a second or two difference, but most of them are processed the exact same second, the logs contain the exact same timestamp as each other.

This leads me to think that it isn't a user resubmitting it, as there should be at least a few seconds between each request if that was the case.

Comment: is there any ajax involved in the submitting?

Comment: Nope, other than the script to diable the submit button onclick, there's no JS on the page.

Comment: Javascript is disabled and the user is double clicking the submit button?

Comment: i can think of some potential network issues that could be at fault - but the solution is still server side validation to stop duplicates

Comment: 1) check if `$_POST` isn't empty before you submit the form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dagon says, server-side checks are your friend here. Give each instance of the form a randomly generated key (guid would be nice), and store that in the database. Don't accept forms that contain a key that already exists in the db.

Also, are you simply displaying HTML after your form processing logic executes? If so, try redirecting after you process the form.

Comment: depending on your form and process just checking a few details and a time stamp may be sufficient. If 'bob' paid the same amount within the last minute them its a duplicate, or if the payment id has been used before or - hard to know with out more data.

Comment: Thanks guys, I guess I'll just have to go with implementing a solution without being positive on the cause of the problem. I guess there's no way to figure out the cause without physically watching someone reproduce it.

Comment: Yup. I'm betting if you fiddle with that back button, you could reproduce it, though :-)

Comment: Not without encountering a dialog asking me if i want to resubmit, though the target demographic is 40-60 year olds, so chances are they're using IE6. Even then, I don't think someone could resubmit the request the EXACT same second by reloading the page.

Comment: Maybe they're double clicking and beating your JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

It is a way: after user presses form submit button, disable it with javascript. That should prevent user from double submitting the form accidently. It works for all sites we implement it like because. Because sometimes user gets impatient and clicks form submit button several times, thats why you get double requests. What you need to make sure it works for all the browsers (disabling the button I mean).

Also you could do it on server side, it just is harder.

We use similar to the upvoted answer in [Enable/disable submit button with jQuery and Coldfusion server code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341784/need-help-with-enable-disable-submit-button-with-jquery-and-coldfusion-server-co)